# Jpa upsert in MySql

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa, upsert

I want to know if there is a way to perform upsert in MySql with spring data jpa.

When I save with the same primary key, the operation fails with a "duplicate primary key" error or something like that..

But I have seen the same operation work with Nosql like Cosmos db where the ID and partition key combo identifies and updates the duplicate record without any error..

Is this possible with mysql and jpa ?

Comment: If primary key is set properly, in spring data jpa `repository.save(...)` doing upsert.

Comment: Nope. It throws SQL Error code 1062.